# How can I use a specific python interpreter to run my python file

Tags: python, module, virtualenv, pythoninterpreter

I created a python file and used some packages. I installed packages on a virtual Environment. Now, when I try to run that file, it run on the default installed interpreter and I have to activate the virtual Environment every time I have to run that file. Is there any way possible to do that.
In conclusion: The code from which the file can select the place where to look for the packages.

Comment: It would be good to give more information about the paths and operating system you use to create a better answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the path to the virtual environment's interpreter directly to the shebang at the top of the script. For example, if your virtual environment is stored at `/home/ishant/venv`, the shebang would be

```
#!/home/ishant/venv/bin/python
```

Then, if you execute your script directly (after making it executable with `chmod +x` or the like), your virtual environment will be used.

(Activating a virtual environment simply updates your `PATH` variable so that `python` resolves to the virtual environment, rather than your "regular" environment. You can always access the tools in the virtual enivironment directly instead.)

Comment: This makes it usable from bash with direct execution, but only for user 'ishant'. Do only use that for single user experiments.

Comment: I am on windows. and can you specify how can i use "shebang". I have no idea about that. I just copied what you gave me and pasted it over.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the common ways of executing a Python script under Windows.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653317/9857620 there's a windows solution with absolute paths (shebang is posix only).

Answer (score 0):

## Command line only (Linux)

Put this in your ~/.bashrc and create the virtual env with name 'venv' inside the project root:

```sh
function cd() {
  if [[ -d ./venv ]] ; then
    deactivate
  fi

  builtin cd $1

  if [[ -d ./venv ]] ; then
    . ./venv/bin/activate
  fi
}
```

When cd-ing into a directory, it searches for a virtualenv named venv and disables when leaving.

## Alternative with absolute paths (Linux and Windows)

In cases where you want to run the script without a bash, you could run it with the absolute path to the python interpreter inside the virtualenv.

This is from **inside the project** dir:

```sh
# Posix:
/path/to/virtualenvname/bin/python run.py

# Windows:
C:\path\to\virtualenvname\Scripts\python.exe run.py
```

Or if you want to execute it from **outside of the project dir**:

```sh
# Posix:
/path/to/virtualenvname/bin/python /path/to/projectdir/run.py

# Windows:
C:\path\to\virtualenvname\Scripts\python.exe C:\path\to\projectdir\run.py
```

Comment: Note that this won't actually work when running the script from anywhere but its own directory (actually, the ``venv``'s if the two aren't the same). It won't work when invoking the script via the ``PATH`` or any non-trivial absolute/relative path.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I edited my post.

Answer (score -2):

Okk So i got your point what i think is why not to add some function in your code so that whenever you excute it it will automatically use vitual environment

**--code for linux**

```
import os

os.system("source <virtualenv_name>/bin/activate")
```

**--code for windows**

```
import os

os.system("<virtualenv_name>/bin/activate")
```

And at last line add

```
os.system("deactivate")
```

Add these lines to beginning of your programm see if it works.

May this help you solving your probelem

Thanks!!

Comment: It says source is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: This forces everyone working with your code to create this virtualenv. Do only use that for single user experiments.

Comment: See i have edited my answer again hope it works for you !!

Comment: Did you actually try these? ``source`` and the ``activate`` script set the environments *in the current shell* – which is gone once ``os.system`` completes.

Comment: i added the new one for windows but now its saying that:
`'venv' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

and this is what i added to it:
```
import os

os.system("venv/Scripts/activate")
```